# Ruby remove duplicate entries in array of hashes but based on more than one value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-2.0

I've seen numerous questions about this but only with one key, never for multiple keys.

I have the following array of hashes:

```
a = [{:name=>"Yes, Yes, Yes", :artist=>"Some Dude", :composer=> 'First Dude', :duration=>"3:21"},
 {:name=>"Chick on the Side", :artist=>"Another Dude", :duration=>"3:20"},
 {:name=>"Luv Is", :duration=>"3:13"},
 {:name=>"Yes, Yes, Yes", :artist=>"Some Dude", :composer=> 'First Dude', :duration=>"2"},
 {:name=>"Chick on the Side", :artist=>"Another Dude"}]
```

`a.uniq` won't work here because the duration is different or might not even exist. I have a unique key set up in the database that does not allow duplicate entries by the same name, artist and composer so I sometimes get errors when people have duplicate entries for these 3 keys.

**Is there a way to run `uniq` that would check for those 3 keys?** I tried a block like this:

```
 new_tracks.uniq do |a_track|
   a_track[:name]
   a_track[:artist]
   a_track[:composer]
 end
```

But that ignores anything where the key is not present (any entry without a composer does not meet the above criteria for example).

I could always use just the `:name` key but that would mean I'm getting rid of potentially valid tracks in compilations that have the same title but different artist or composer.

This is with Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) accepts a block. If a block is given, it will use the return value of the block for comparison.

Your code was close to the solution, but in your code the return value was only `a_track[:composer]` which is the last evaluated statement.

You can join the attributes you want into a string and return that string.

```
new_tracks.uniq { |track| [track[:name], track[:artist], track[:composer]].join(":") }
```

A possible refactoring is

```
new_tracks.uniq { |track| track.attributes.slice('name', 'artist', 'composer').values.join(":") }
```

Or add a custom method in your model that performs the join, and call it

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  def digest
    attributes.slice('name', 'artist', 'composer').values.join(":")
  end
end

new_tracks.uniq(&:digest)
```

Comment: Great, **thanks a lot!** The first one works fine: `.uniq { |track| [track[:name], track[:artist], track[:composer]].join(":") }`. The second one gives me an error `SyntaxError: unexpected '}', expecting ']'`. If I fix that, then I get `undefined method `attributes'`. But the first one does the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: AFAIK, `attributes` is an ActiveRecord-ism that only works on instances of ActiveRecord::Base.  If you're using raw Hashes, use `values_at(:name, :artist, :composer)` instead of `attributes.slice('name', 'artist', 'composer').values`.

Comment: For activerecord result it needs to be converted to array.
products.to_ary.uniq { |p| [p.code, p.price] }

otherwise you will bang your head for hours

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it is to use values_at. if you don't want to use slice and join

```
a.uniq {|hash| hash.values_at(:name, :composer, :artist)}
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion, @sujay.  `Hash::values_at` in general is great, and can be used as a form of Hash destructuring.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question, it's just a matter of using the right combination of data inside the `uniq` block:

```
a = [
  {:name=>"Yes, Yes, Yes", :artist=>"Some Dude", :composer=> 'First Dude', :duration=>"3:21"},
  {:name=>"Yes, Yes, Yes", :artist=>"Some Dude", :composer=> 'First Dude', :duration=>"2"},
  {:name=>"Chick on the Side", :artist=>"Another Dude", :duration=>"3:20"},
  {:name=>"Chick on the Side", :artist=>"Another Dude"},
  {:name=>"Luv Is", :duration=>"3:13"},
]

a.uniq{ |a_track|
  [
    a_track[:name],
    a_track[:artist],
    a_track[:composer],
  ]
}
```

Which would return:

```
[
  {:name=>"Yes, Yes, Yes", :artist=>"Some Dude", :composer=>"First Dude", :duration=>"3:21"},
  {:name=>"Chick on the Side", :artist=>"Another Dude", :duration=>"3:20"},
  {:name=>"Luv Is", :duration=>"3:13"}
]
```

`uniq` lets us create anything inside its block, and uses that for its comparison. I'm choosing to use an array, because Ruby knows how to compare arrays, but the value could be a MD5 checksum or a CRC check if that made sense:

```
a.uniq{ |a_track|
  OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.digest(a_track[:name] + (a_track[:artist] || '') + (a_track[:composer] || ''))
} 
# => [{:name=>"Yes, Yes, Yes", :artist=>"Some Dude", :composer=>"First Dude", :duration=>"3:21"}, {:name=>"Chick on the Side", :artist=>"Another Dude", :duration=>"3:20"}, {:name=>"Luv Is", :duration=>"3:13"}]
```

I have to use `(a_track[:artist] || '')` because we can't concatenate a `nil` to a String, so `|| ''` returns an empty string instead.

Comment: This is interesting, I like this approach: `a.uniq { |a_track| [ a_track[:name], a_track[:artist], a_track[:composer] ] }` I saw Simone's answer first so I accepted that as the answer, but I like this one better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also `to_s` each value, which should convert any nils into empty strings.

Comment: We can, but it hides intent.